# Harddisk spinning when plugging/unplugging laptop

Tags: hard-drive, power-management, ssd, battery, tlp

Im setting power management on my linux as I'm using laptop. I found on the internet that one good software is TLP, which helps power management. I have Acer Aspire V15 Nitro which have combination of HDD and SSD. I have Linux on SSD and Windows on HDD. For power consumption reasons, for lifespan reasons and any others it's good when HDD is not rotating (being in standby mode). I can set harddisk timeout and APM in TLP but I got one problem and don't know how to fix it.

Whenever I change the state of laptop, be it plugging to AC or unpluggin, making it run on battery, harddisk always starts to spinning. It like wakes up because of something, and then, after timeout time it stops spinning once again.

I would like to change that but don't know how, and if it is possible, I'd like to set somehow harddisk if it is mounted, then it shouldn't stop spinning (as I got movies and music on harddisk and always making it to spin-down after timeout set in TLP is wearing it out much more then just spinning around all the time while I watch the movie for example).

If there is someone who can help, I'd appreciate help. :) Thanks in advance.

P.S.: If you know any other "better" way how to conserve battery (power management) on Linux, let me know (because Windows is much better in this as it is commercial ;) we all know that).